# Directions to the Algebra Zoo?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a good resources that lists known algebraic structures? I'm thinking of something like Scott Aaronson's [Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo) or the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/), both of which have entries for various complexity classes/integer sequences, their properties, and relationships among them. You can cobble together something like this from the Wikipedia page on [Algebraic Structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure), but I was hoping there was something more comprehensive.

To clarify, I'm looking for something that has lots of specific examples of rings, groups, lattices, etc, not just a list of the various kinds.

Comment: Do you mean types of structures, as on the Algebraic Structures Wiki page, or individual structures (e.g., information about particular important groups, rings, etc.)?

Comment: The latter, yes.

Comment: This is absolutely nothing like a database, but it is instructive: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29006/counterexamples-in-algebra

Comment: @Nathan I have been thinking same thing recently, would you like to build one with me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only applies to groups, but [Groupprops](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page) ("The Group Properties Wiki") records numerous properties for a large selection of important groups.